# Preserving formatting to Excel using Shiny downloadhandler

Tags: r, download, shiny, formatting

I wrote a code that formats to green if the index > 120 and to red if the index is < 80. It works when I view it in web browser. See below.

[image]

But when I download the data using downloadHandler, the formatting is gone. How I preserve the formatting? 
Thank you.

My code:
server.R:

```
function(input, output, session) {

    A <- c(121, 89, 150, 99)
    B <- c(41, 89, 112, 199)
    C <- c(143, 129, 50, 80)

    data <- data.frame(A, B, C)


    output$index <- DT::renderDataTable({
        brks    <- c(80,120)
        colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("indianred1","white","mediumseagreen"))
        clrs    <- colfunc(length(brks) + 1) 

        DT::datatable(data, class= 'compact stripe', caption = '', rownames = F, options = list(autoWidth = FALSE, scrollX = TRUE, columnDefs = list(list(width = '300px', targets = 1), list(className = 'dt-left', targets="_all")), paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE)) %>% formatStyle(c('A','B','C'), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))   

    }) 


    output$download_index <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {paste("Indices.xlsx")},
      content  = function(file) {
        write.xlsx(x = data, file, sheetName = "Profile", row.names= F, col.names = T, append=F)

      }
    )
}
```

ui.R:

```
fluidPage(title = "Profiling",

    column(DT::dataTableOutput('index'), width=10),

    fluidRow(align="bottom", column(3, offset=0, style='padding:0px;', downloadButton('download_index', "Save")))

)
```

Comment: The underlying `write.xlsx` function doesn't do conditional formatting, and certainly wouldn't interpret such formatting from `DT::datatable`.  I think you'll need to detail the conditional formatting using the appropriate functions in `openxlsx` as a second step.

Comment: try `webshot` -- it takes a snapshot of the html. not the most elegant, but it's effective.